# Zombie mvn: Maven uninstall troubles

Tags: maven

I am currently struggling with an uninstalled maven 3.3.9 on my Ubuntu 16.04, which I uninstalled using the command
    `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove maven`
I have installed maven 3.6.1 in my local directory,
and command `which mvn` points exactly to the executable,
but when I'm trying to execute the command `mvn --version` it shows File not found (at the old /usr/bin path of the uninstalled 3.3.9 version)

`bash: /usr/bin/mvn: File not found`

So, obviously, there is some symbolic link or something else, but trying to find the broken link with the command
`find . -type l | xargs file | grep broken` from `/`
does not come up with any **mvn** link.

That's rather annoying, can please someone give me an idea how to get rid of the zombie mvn?

Comment: `apt remove` leaves the configuration of the package behind. Try doing an `apt purge maven`... this might fix it, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Augusto: that was it, thanksalot!